# openpyxl module - can't find openpyxl.utils.dataframe.dataframe_to_rows function

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am currently working with Pandas and Excel and am using the openpyxl module.

I am attempting to write a DataFrame to excel, and the openpyxl documentation states that one should use the "openpyxl.utils.dataframe.dataframe_to_rows()" function. (http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/pandas.html)

However when I try to use it I get the following error:

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

ImportError: No module named 'openpyxl.utils.dataframe'
```

I have tried:

```
import openpyxl.utils
```

Which works with no issues.

Also when I run:

```
dir(openpyxl.utils)
```

I don't see any mention of "dataframe".

Am I doing something wrong, or is the documentation for openpyxl out of date?

Anyone have any ideas about how i can easily transfer a dataframe into an excel workbook that i have opened with openpyxl?

Comment: Check which version of openpyxl you're using.

Comment: Thanks! that was exactly the problem - I had version 2.3.2 and I upgraded to version 2.4.1 at which point the import worked. much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer from Charlie Clark -  I had version 2.3.2 and I upgraded to version 2.4.1 at which point the import worked.

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
import openpyxl.utils.dataframe
```