# openpyxl 2.5.1 - AttributeError: module 'openpyxl.utils' has no attribute 'dataframe'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl 2.5.1 to export a dataframe from pandas to Excel and I need the function

```
openpyxl.utils.dataframe.dataframe_to_rows
```

as written in the [documentation page](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.utils.dataframe.html#openpyxl.utils.dataframe.dataframe_to_rows). However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'openpyxl.utils' has no attribute 'dataframe'
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974626/openpyxl-module-cant-find-openpyxl-utils-dataframe-dataframe-to-rows-function) that addresses the same problem, but the answer only points out that it is an issue due to version upgrading, without actually showing how to solve it.

I could not find any change in the documentation, therefore I am wondering where that function has been moved to.

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

PS I have to use this approach because I need to append data in an Excel worksheet without destroying the pivot tables on another worksheet.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version. `openpyxl.__version__` it should be 2.5.1

Comment: @Chris As I wrote, I am using version 2.5.1

Comment: This is how module namespaces work in Python.

Comment: @CharlieClark What do you mean? I should be able to call a function either way, shouldn't I?

Comment: Obviously not which is why you get the exception.

Comment: @CharlieClark Then could you please be a bit less concise and enlighten me? How do I know when I can do a direct call and when I have to import the (sub)module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
```

Comment: @Lightspark Updated. I have tested that now this will work.

Comment: It works, thank you! But then I am wondering why one should import the function from the module and cannot call it directly by using the whole syntax... this seems quite weird to me. Can you explain that?

Comment: @Lightspark I'm not 100% sure why but it happens for some functions within some libraries. It's probably depends on how the authors structure the codebase.